Does it make sense that the performance of XG Boost varies dramatically from two machines holding all hyperparameters fixed?
I am hyperparameter tuning an xgboost model and I am finding that depending if I train the model locally on my machine vs on AWS sagemaker, I get quite different results.
Running cross-validation locally for a certain set of hyperparameters yields a mean R^2 score of around ~0.23 and for the same hyperparameters on sagemaker, I get a mean R^2 of around ~0.7.
I know that xgboost is non-deterministic in general but I wouldn't expect the performance to vary so greatly. How much impact does the difference in CPU that sagemaker is using vs locally make? In other words I am trying to gauge if this difference in performance is unsurprising or surprising. If it is surprising, that likely means I didn't set up the comparison correctly. If it is unsurprising, is there any way I can make the performance align more closely between the two machines?
Thanks.

To me that sounds like a big gap for any model. You can control for randomness by setting the numpy, random, and other seeds.
Can you check what hyperparameters sagemaker lands on? If you take its optimal hyperparameters, and apply them to your local model, you should get similar results to sagemaker.
If not, one issue could be that the train/val sets between the local machine and sagemaker are somehow very different. Apparently the local copy is missing some informative features, or the target has been distorted.
It's worth noting how many hyperparameter combinations sagemaker is testing compared to your local set up - perhaps it's trying a lot more samples, or is exploring a larger search space if they're configured differently.

so what i found out what was happening was that the order of the columns that I was passing to XGBoost was non-deterministic because I was using set a few times in my code. And apparently, the order of the columns affects the performance of xgboost. So regardless of whether I was running it locally, or on sagemaker, I would get different results every time I executed the script. Purging my code of set, made my results deterministic.
